# How shorten fixme's name in its notes?

Tags: fixme

Each use of `\fxnote[<some text>]` from the `fixme` package produces a note containing not just the argument <*some text*> but also prepended the label "FiXme:", as shown in the example below.

How can that be modfied so that the "FiXme:" is changed to something shorter (e.g., just "FX ") or even omitted entirely?

My aim is to shorten that label in the output so as to leave more room for the actual note.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\fxsetup{layout=margin}
\fxusetheme{color}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Stuff}\fxnote{find a better chapter title}

\lipsum[1]\fxnote{check this}

\end{document}
```

[image: fixme-fxnote-how-shorten-label]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “FiXme” you're seeing is actually an author name reverting to the default value. You can specify the author name on the `\usepackage` by writing something like `\usepackage[author=FX]{fixme}` or even `\usepackage[author=]{fixme}` to eliminate the tag entirely.

This is documented in section 3.12.1 of the fixme package documentation.